# How to conditionally format decimal places in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, formatting, ms-office

I was wondering how to conditionally format decimal places for certain text boxes in a report? I need to so certain text boxes show 2 decimal places if the value in them is > 1 and 3 decimal places if the value in them is < 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with conditional format (number formats aren't available there), but you can do it in the query that is the record source for the report:

```
SELECT 
    IIf([myNumber]>=1, 
        Format([myNumber],"0.00"), 
        Format([myNumber],"0.000")
        ) AS FormattedNumber,
    ... other fields ...
FROM myTable
```

Note that this yields a string, not a number, so you can't use this field to calculate a sum or similar.

Comment: Alternatively you could apply `IIf` to only the format pattern ...  `Format(MyNumber, IIf(MyNumber > 1, "0.00", "0.000"))`

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work. The textboxes are a calculated field.

Comment: Yeah, the textboxes are calculated fields :/

Comment: Then move their calculation to the query instead of the report. Or include the `IIf( , Format1, Format2)` in the calculation on the report. For more help, post how they are calculated.